# Creating Range<String.Index> from constant Ints

Tags: string, swift, range, swift2

What is wrong with this piece of code for constructing a range that should then serve in a call to `substringWithRange`?

```
let range = Range<String.Index>(start: 0, end: 3)
```

The Swift compiler (in Xcode 7.1.1) marks it with this error message:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<Index>' with an argument list of type '(start: Int, end: Int)'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reference the startIndex of a specific string, then advance:

```
let longString = "Supercalifragilistic"
let startIndex = longString.startIndex
let range = Range(start: startIndex, end: startIndex.advancedBy(3))
```

Comment: Alternative syntax: `let range = startIndex ..< startIndex.advancedBy(3)`.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various ways

```
let startIndex = text.startIndex
let endIndex = text.endIndex

var range1 = startIndex.advancedBy(1) ..< text.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
var range2 = startIndex.advancedBy(0) ..< startIndex.advancedBy(5)
var range3 = startIndex ..< endIndex
```

let substring = text.substringWithRange(range)