# Swift substring initialization

Tags: swift3, substring

Currently I am trying to mess with this in playground before I implement some version of this into my actual code. I am trying to take a string and print out 4 characters. The code that is shown below, I am planning on using in a loop and increment the starting and ending position by 4 which is why there are variables currently at the starting and ending points. Before I can even get there however, I am getting an error:

> error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range' with an argument list of type '(start: String.CharacterView.Index, end: String.CharacterView.Index)'

`var str_start = 0`

`var str_end = 4`

```
let sub_str =  initial_str.substring(Range<String.Index>(start: initial_str.startIndex.advancedBy(str_start), end: initial_str.endIndex.advancedBy(str_end)))
```

I've already looked at these sources but to no avail:

[Creating Range<String.Index> from constant Ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815495/creating-rangestring-index-from-constant-ints)

[Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(start: String.Index, end: String.Index)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802773/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, and I apologize if it is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
let initialString = "foo bar"

let newStartIndex = initialString.index(initialString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let newEndIndex = initialString.index(initialString.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
let substring = initialString[newStartIndex..<newEndIndex]

// this also works, but it needs `import Foundation`:
// let substring = initialString.substring(with: newStartIndex..<newEndIndex)

print(substring)
```

Output:

```
oo ba
```

Comment: swiftConventionIsToUseCamelCase not snake_case

Comment: Perfect, I can make this work just like I wanted to with the original code. Thank you very much